# JSON HTTP request payload parsed in Swift is being interpreted by Express as single key in a JSON object–insight as to why?

Tags: json, swift, rest, http, encoding

I am working on some networking code in an iOS app with Swift and having an issue where a `Codable` struct is being parsed into JSON improperly, in such a way that the whole object is used as the key

My `Codable` struct called UserForLogin to be parsed as the body of a login request. The struct has the following code:

```
struct UserForLogin: Encodable, Equatable {
    let email: String
    let password: String
    
    init(email: String, password: String) {
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
    }
}
```

`signIn` looks like this:

```
func signIn(with data: UserForLogin) -> AnyPublisher<UserLoginDTO?, Error> {
        return gcNetworkService.post(to: AuthModuleEndpoint.signin, data: data, with: [])
            .tryMap { userWithToken -> UserLoginDTO in
                return userWithToken
            }.mapError { error in
                return error
            }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

and the `.post` method essentially calls another method called `send` which contains this code snippet:

```
var request = createURLRequest(for: requestURL)
request.httpMethod = method 

let requestData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(data)
        
request.httpBody = requestData
        
return session.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
```

When I make this call, however, the request body that my backend receives is:

`{ '{"email":"test","password":"test2"}': '' }`

Essentially, the whole object is being parsed as one JSON key rather than with each variable as a key and value as a value, etc. like it should.

For context, I'm successfully handling requests in the backend when sending them through Postman, so I don't think it's a server-side issue.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with your code. And the example you posted looks like valid json to me. But you are missing the `content-type`. Perhaps this will solve your issue: `request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`

Comment: @Jacob that solved it, thank you friend! Go by the single-quotes in my example to see why it was incorrect :-)

Comment: Glad it helped. If you're decoding the response, you might also want to add this just in case: `request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")`. This will tell the server you expect a  json response so it doesn't send you XML or HTML or some garbage you can't use.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Jacob for pointing out I was missing this line:

`request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`

This solved the problem.